# What is それ in それどころ pointing at in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> > 溺れる者は藁をも掴む。溺れる火口はレムにもすがる。
> >
> > 返って自分の首を絞めてしまう結果に終わりました。それどころか頼みの綱のレムにさえ破滅への道程を勧められ、それと知らずに「レム、お前頭いいな」などと頓珍漢な賛辞を送ってしまいます。

The context is that 火口 is being led to a trap(he's going to a place where he's gonna be arrested), unbeknown to him. He then asks his supposed ally Rem for her opinion and she says he should go.

As for それどころか I don't know what それ is refering to.

In this sentence:

> 私は今回の試験は簡単だろうと思っていたが、それどころか追試を受けることになってしまった。

It's clear that それ is pointing at the previous statement  and what follows next is contradicting/negating that statement. A good translation of それどころか in this case is "Contrary to that". But I don't think it follows the same pattern for それどころか頼みの綱のレムにさえ破滅への道程を勧められ

Comment: Is 返って the correct kanji?

Comment: @Fireheart251 yes. At first I thought 返って自分の首を絞めてしまう結果に終わりました was "By going back(returning home) he would be sealing his own fate" but that wouldn't be the case here. Then I found some examples that led me to thing that this could be translated as "Opposite to his expectations, he would end up sealing his own fate"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 返って自分の首を絞めてしまう結果に終わりました。**それどころか**頼みの綱のレムにさえ破滅への道程を勧められ、それと知らずに「レム、お前頭いいな」などと頓珍漢な賛辞を送ってしまいます。

In this context, 「それどころか」 is fairly synonymous to 「そんなものではなく」 or 「そんな生易{なまやさ}しいものではなく」, which means "***not as simple as that***", etc.

In the pattern:

> 「Statement A。それどころか + Statement B。」

The author thinks Statement A was an understatement or too simplistic a way to describe what *really* took place.　Therefore, s/he goes ahead and adds a more descriptive sentence to augment it.

Therefore, you are correct in stating that the 「それどころか」 used in the sentence:

> 私は今回の試験は簡単だろうと思っていたが、**それどころか**追試を受けることになってしまった。

is different in meaning.  That indeed means "***on the contrary***".

My own TL (85% literal & 15% free) of the original sentence:

> "Instead, he ended up asking for trouble.  It was not even quite as simple as that.  He was suggested to take the way to destruction by Rem, whom he trusted much, and not knowing this, he even paid Rem the highest compliment 'Hey, Rem, you're so smart!'"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's saying 火口 dug his own grave, but even worse, he was lead to his grave by his own comrade.